# WiFi Calling on an Unsecured network

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat, voip, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I recently upgraded from a Samsung Galaxy S7 Active to an S8 Active(G892A). In doing so I have encountered an issue with the new OS and WiFi calling. Thus far, I have been unable to establish a WiFi Calling session in the OS (7.0 Nougat) when connected to an Unsecure guest network - which happens to be the only option for data at work as the building is not suitable for cell service. When at home, I am able to establish a connection to the service.

This was not an issue with my previous GS7 Active running Android 6.Som.Ething

Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any insight into fixing it?

I have a sneaking suspicion it might have something to do with security certificate requirements

New Tag for WiFi-Calling? VoIP?